# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: arrays, oracle, loops, for-loop

Im trying to execute the code below. I've created a array and want to insert every element of this array into a existing table. I've used a for loop for this. But I get the following error:  "ORA-00984: column not allowed here". What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE
   TYPE array_status IS VARRAY(2) OF VARCHAR2(30); 
   ARRAY array_status := array_status('Planned', 'Finished');
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO STATUS_DIM(STATUSNAAM) VALUES(' || ARRAY(i) || ')'; 
      dbms_output.put_line(array(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL at all? That is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are concatenating the value into the SQL string which results in something like this: `INSERT INTO STATUS_DIM(STATUSNAAM) VALUES(Planned);` but the values should be put between single quotes: `INSERT INTO STATUS_DIM(STATUSNAAM) VALUES('Planned');`

The correct solution is to use a bind variable:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE array_status IS VARRAY(2) OF VARCHAR2(30); 
   ARRAY array_status := array_status('Planned', 'Finished');
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO STATUS_DIM(STATUSNAAM) VALUES(:status)' using array(i); 
      dbms_output.put_line(array(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then you don't need to think about quoting.

Actually you don't need dynamic SQL for this at all:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE array_status IS VARRAY(2) OF VARCHAR2(30); 
   ARRAY array_status := array_status('Planned', 'Finished');
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
     INSERT INTO STATUS_DIM(STATUSNAAM) VALUES(array(i)); 
     dbms_output.put_line(array(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The most efficient solution however, is to use `FORALL` instead of a loop.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE array_status IS VARRAY(2) OF VARCHAR2(30); 
   ARRAY array_status := array_status('Planned', 'Finished');
BEGIN
   FORALL i IN 1..ARRAY.COUNT 
     INSERT INTO STATUS_DIM(STATUSNAAM) VALUES(array(i)); 
END;
/
```

That will be faster than a "plain loop" but has the drawback that you can't use `dbms_output` for eachelement.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know how to bind a variable. I've implemented your solution without dynamic SQL. Because like u said, it isnt necessary.